# How to recover the ID of a Picker in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

You have a Picker in Xamarin that displays the name of certain Fabricantes, as follows

[image]

this picker is filled by passing an ObservableCollection of the FABRICANTES object

Fabricantes.CS:

```
 public class Fabricante
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int  Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

FiltrosView.XAML:

```
 <Picker Title="Seleccione Fabricante"               
                Margin="15,5,15,5"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Fabricantes, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Id}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}">         
        </Picker>
```

How do I fill the Picker?
Here I declare the list and the property that will capture the ID of the picker, to open the list in the picker, I will cast the object that arrives from an API and will fill the Observable collection and then bindarla in sight, it WORKS!

FiltrosViewModel.CS:

```
      public ObservableCollection<Fabricante> Fabricantes { get; set; }

       public int IdSustancia
        {
            get
            {
                return idSustancia;
            }
            set
            {
                if (idSustancia != value)
                {
                    idSustancia = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IdSustancia)));
                }
            }
        }

     var response = await apiService.GetList<Fabricante>(urlService, param);

        var list = (List<Fabricante>)response.Result;
        Fabricantes.Clear();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
           Fabricantes.Add(item);
        }
```

But, since I capture the ID (int) of the value that the user entered (string), can this be done in xamarin?
I would like to be able to capture the value of the ID of the picker in the property IdSubstance declared previously, how to do it? any help for me?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing that is binding the selected index of the picker. In your XAML code, add the following line to your picker:

```
SelectedIndex={Binding IdSustancia, Mode=TwoWay}
```

So, when index != -1 (initial value), you can get Fabricante's ID in your ObservableCollection, accessing `Fabricantes[IdSustancia]`.

Comment: I am trying to access the index with Fabricantes[IdSustancia] and I get the error:  "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" @DanielCunha

Comment: How are you doing the binding? And where is the rest of IdSustancia? Here's an example of how you should do it: https://github.com/danielccunha/Recipes-Book/, look for ViewModel SearchMealsPageViewModel.cs and View SearchMealsPage

Answer (score 0):

use the `SelectedItem` property

```
SelectedItem="{Binding IdSustancia}"
```

however, for this to work you need to bind it to a property of type `Fabricante`.

Comment: You say bindar the picker to an item that is NOT a list? I understand well? Could you exemplify and complete your answer? @Jason

Comment: you would still bind ItemsSource to a List.  But SelectedItem represents the item the user actually chose, so it is only a single item.